# DataFrame not getting recognised despite being called over in previous cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a new variable by using the sample function, taking the data from a previous DataFrame.Having already used the 'companies' frame earlier, now it's not recognising the DataFrame. How to proceed further?

I was simply trying to execute the code, so that I can call the variable in the upcoming cells.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU5NA.png)

Comment: Please post the code as a text not a screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see [1] on the left by your cell in Jupyter Notebook? It means that this cell is the first one that was executed. It means also that the 'companies' DataFrame does not exist in memory. I guess that your Notebook disconnected. Go to Kernel -> Restart and then run cell from top to your cell of interest. If your 'comnpanies' DataFrame was created in cells above it should work.